# Convert RGB array to HSL

Tags: python, numpy, rgb, hsl

A disclaimer first, I'm not very skilled in Python, you guys have my admiration.

My problem:
I need to generate 10k+ images from templates (128px by 128px) with various hues and luminances.

I load the images and turn them into arrays

```
image = Image.open(dir + "/" + file).convert('RGBA')
arr=np.array(np.asarray(image).astype('float'))
```

From what I can understand, handling numpy arrays in this fashion is much faster than looping over every pixels and using colorsys.

Now, I've stumbled upon a couple functions to convert rgb to hsv.
This helped me generate my images with different hues, but I also need to play with the brightness so that some can be black, and others white.

```
def rgb_to_hsv(rgb):
    # Translated from source of colorsys.rgb_to_hsv
    hsv=np.empty_like(rgb)
    hsv[...,3:]=rgb[...,3:]
    r,g,b=rgb[...,0],rgb[...,1],rgb[...,2]
    maxc = np.max(rgb[...,:2],axis=-1)
    minc = np.min(rgb[...,:2],axis=-1)    
    hsv[...,2] = maxc   
    hsv[...,1] = (maxc-minc) / maxc
    rc = (maxc-r) / (maxc-minc)
    gc = (maxc-g) / (maxc-minc)
    bc = (maxc-b) / (maxc-minc)
    hsv[...,0] = np.select([r==maxc,g==maxc],[bc-gc,2.0+rc-bc],default=4.0+gc-rc)
    hsv[...,0] = (hsv[...,0]/6.0) % 1.0
    idx=(minc == maxc)
    hsv[...,0][idx]=0.0
    hsv[...,1][idx]=0.0
    return hsv

def hsv_to_rgb(hsv):
    # Translated from source of colorsys.hsv_to_rgb
    rgb=np.empty_like(hsv)
    rgb[...,3:]=hsv[...,3:]    
    h,s,v=hsv[...,0],hsv[...,1],hsv[...,2]   
    i = (h*6.0).astype('uint8')
    f = (h*6.0) - i
    p = v*(1.0 - s)
    q = v*(1.0 - s*f)
    t = v*(1.0 - s*(1.0-f))
    i = i%6
    conditions=[s==0.0,i==1,i==2,i==3,i==4,i==5]
    rgb[...,0]=np.select(conditions,[v,q,p,p,t,v],default=v)
    rgb[...,1]=np.select(conditions,[v,v,v,q,p,p],default=t)
    rgb[...,2]=np.select(conditions,[v,p,t,v,v,q],default=p) 
    return rgb
```

How easy is it to modify these functions to convert to and from HSL?
Any trick to convert HSV to HSL?

Any info you can give me is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, **`numpy`**, namely the vectorised code, can speed-up color conversions.

The more, **for massive production** of 10k+ bitmaps, you may want to re-use a ready made professional conversion, or sub-class it, if it is not exactly matching your preferred Luminance model.

a Computer Vision library OpenCV, currently available for python as a **`cv2`** module, can take care of the colorsystem conversion without any additional coding just with:

### a ready-made conversion one-liner

```
out = cv2.cvtColor(   anInputFRAME, cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR ) # a bitmap conversion
```

A list of some color-systems available in `cv2` ( you may notice **`RGB`** to be referred to as **`BRG`** due to OpenCV convention of a different ordering of an image's **B**lue-**R**ed-**G**reen color-planes ),

( symmetry applies `COLOR_YCR_CB2BGR` <-|-> `COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB` not all pairs shown )

```
>>> import cv2
>>> for key in dir( cv2 ):                              # show all ready conversions
...     if key[:7] == 'COLOR_Y':
...         print key

COLOR_YCR_CB2BGR
COLOR_YCR_CB2RGB
COLOR_YUV2BGR
COLOR_YUV2BGRA_I420
COLOR_YUV2BGRA_IYUV
COLOR_YUV2BGRA_NV12
COLOR_YUV2BGRA_NV21
COLOR_YUV2BGRA_UYNV
COLOR_YUV2BGRA_UYVY
COLOR_YUV2BGRA_Y422
COLOR_YUV2BGRA_YUNV
COLOR_YUV2BGRA_YUY2
COLOR_YUV2BGRA_YUYV
COLOR_YUV2BGRA_YV12
COLOR_YUV2BGRA_YVYU
COLOR_YUV2BGR_I420
COLOR_YUV2BGR_IYUV
COLOR_YUV2BGR_NV12
COLOR_YUV2BGR_NV21
COLOR_YUV2BGR_UYNV
COLOR_YUV2BGR_UYVY
COLOR_YUV2BGR_Y422
COLOR_YUV2BGR_YUNV
COLOR_YUV2BGR_YUY2
COLOR_YUV2BGR_YUYV
COLOR_YUV2BGR_YV12
COLOR_YUV2BGR_YVYU
COLOR_YUV2GRAY_420
COLOR_YUV2GRAY_I420
COLOR_YUV2GRAY_IYUV
COLOR_YUV2GRAY_NV12
COLOR_YUV2GRAY_NV21
COLOR_YUV2GRAY_UYNV
COLOR_YUV2GRAY_UYVY
COLOR_YUV2GRAY_Y422
COLOR_YUV2GRAY_YUNV
COLOR_YUV2GRAY_YUY2
COLOR_YUV2GRAY_YUYV
COLOR_YUV2GRAY_YV12
COLOR_YUV2GRAY_YVYU
COLOR_YUV2RGB
COLOR_YUV2RGBA_I420
COLOR_YUV2RGBA_IYUV
COLOR_YUV2RGBA_NV12
COLOR_YUV2RGBA_NV21
COLOR_YUV2RGBA_UYNV
COLOR_YUV2RGBA_UYVY
COLOR_YUV2RGBA_Y422
COLOR_YUV2RGBA_YUNV
COLOR_YUV2RGBA_YUY2
COLOR_YUV2RGBA_YUYV
COLOR_YUV2RGBA_YV12
COLOR_YUV2RGBA_YVYU
COLOR_YUV2RGB_I420
COLOR_YUV2RGB_IYUV
COLOR_YUV2RGB_NV12
COLOR_YUV2RGB_NV21
COLOR_YUV2RGB_UYNV
COLOR_YUV2RGB_UYVY
COLOR_YUV2RGB_Y422
COLOR_YUV2RGB_YUNV
COLOR_YUV2RGB_YUY2
COLOR_YUV2RGB_YUYV
COLOR_YUV2RGB_YV12
COLOR_YUV2RGB_YVYU
COLOR_YUV420P2BGR
COLOR_YUV420P2BGRA
COLOR_YUV420P2GRAY
COLOR_YUV420P2RGB
COLOR_YUV420P2RGBA
COLOR_YUV420SP2BGR
COLOR_YUV420SP2BGRA
COLOR_YUV420SP2GRAY
COLOR_YUV420SP2RGB
COLOR_YUV420SP2RGBA
```

I did some prototyping for Luminance conversions ( based on >>> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV )

But not tested for release.

```
def        get_YUV_V_Cr_Rec601_BRG_frame( brgFRAME ):                   # For the Rec. 601 primaries used in gamma-corrected sRGB, fast, VECTORISED MUL/ADD CODE
    out =  numpy.zeros( brgFRAME.shape[0:2] )
    out += 0.615 / 255 * brgFRAME[:,:,1]    # // Red                    # normalise to <0.0 - 1.0> before vectorised MUL/ADD, saves [usec] ... on 480x640 [px] faster goes about 2.2 [msec] instead of 5.4 [msec]
    out -= 0.515 / 255 * brgFRAME[:,:,2]    # // Green
    out -= 0.100 / 255 * brgFRAME[:,:,0]    # // Blue                   # normalise to <0.0 - 1.0> before vectorised MUL/ADD
    return out
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Forgive my ignorance, but is the value I provide to brgFRAME my image numpy array ? I'm getting ValueError: buffer is not large enough

Comment: `brgFRAME` was acquired by a `.read()` method on an instance of a `cv2.VideoCapture(0)`, however it yields a **`numpy.array()`** instance. **What are your `<image>.shape` `.size`, `.dtype` about?**

Comment: Here's what I have so far: http://pastebin.com/dvQHhv5q The templates are png24 with some transparancy.

Comment: Have you traced-back on which line the **`ValueError:`** gets `raise`-d?

Comment: I had the error when using your `get_YUV_V_Cr_Rec601_BRG_frame` method instead of cv2.cvtColor on line 51. Right now, the error I'm getting is on line 51 as well with cv2.cvtColor and says `OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_16U || depth == CV_32F) in cvtColor, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 3642`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll try another approach to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# @File    : rgb2hls.py
# @Info    : @ TSMC
# @Desc    :


import colorsys

import numpy as np
import scipy.misc
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image


def rgb2hls(img):
    """ note: elements in img is a float number less than 1.0 and greater than 0.
    :param img: an numpy ndarray with shape NHWC
    :return:
    """
    assert len(img.shape) == 3
    hue = np.zeros_like(img[:, :, 0])
    luminance = np.zeros_like(img[:, :, 0])
    saturation = np.zeros_like(img[:, :, 0])
    for x in range(height):
        for y in range(width):
            r, g, b = img[x, y]
            h, l, s = colorsys.rgb_to_hls(r, g, b)
            hue[x, y] = h
            luminance[x, y] = l
            saturation[x, y] = s
    return hue, luminance, saturation


def np_rgb2hls(img):
    r, g, b = img[:, :, 0], img[:, :, 1], img[:, :, 2]

    maxc = np.max(img, -1)
    minc = np.min(img, -1)
    l = (minc + maxc) / 2.0
    if np.array_equal(minc, maxc):
        return np.zeros_like(l), l, np.zeros_like(l)
    smask = np.greater(l, 0.5).astype(np.float32)

    s = (1.0 - smask) * ((maxc - minc) / (maxc + minc)) + smask * ((maxc - minc) / (2.001 - maxc - minc))
    rc = (maxc - r) / (maxc - minc + 0.001)
    gc = (maxc - g) / (maxc - minc + 0.001)
    bc = (maxc - b) / (maxc - minc + 0.001)

    rmask = np.equal(r, maxc).astype(np.float32)
    gmask = np.equal(g, maxc).astype(np.float32)
    rgmask = np.logical_or(rmask, gmask).astype(np.float32)

    h = rmask * (bc - gc) + gmask * (2.0 + rc - bc) + (1.0 - rgmask) * (4.0 + gc - rc)
    h = np.remainder(h / 6.0, 1.0)
    return h, l, s


def tf_rgb2hls(img):
    """ note: elements in img all in [0,1]
    :param img: a tensor with shape NHWC
    :return:
    """
    assert img.get_shape()[-1] == 3
    r, g, b = img[:, :, 0], img[:, :, 1], img[:, :, 2]
    maxc = tf.reduce_max(img, -1)
    minc = tf.reduce_min(img, -1)

    l = (minc + maxc) / 2.0

    # if tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(minc, maxc)):
    #     return tf.zeros_like(l), l, tf.zeros_like(l)
    smask = tf.cast(tf.greater(l, 0.5), tf.float32)

    s = (1.0 - smask) * ((maxc - minc) / (maxc + minc)) + smask * ((maxc - minc) / (2.001 - maxc - minc))
    rc = (maxc - r) / (maxc - minc + 0.001)
    gc = (maxc - g) / (maxc - minc + 0.001)
    bc = (maxc - b) / (maxc - minc + 0.001)

    rmask = tf.equal(r, maxc)
    gmask = tf.equal(g, maxc)
    rgmask = tf.cast(tf.logical_or(rmask, gmask), tf.float32)
    rmask = tf.cast(rmask, tf.float32)
    gmask = tf.cast(gmask, tf.float32)

    h = rmask * (bc - gc) + gmask * (2.0 + rc - bc) + (1.0 - rgmask) * (4.0 + gc - rc)
    h = tf.mod(h / 6.0, 1.0)

    h = tf.expand_dims(h, -1)
    l = tf.expand_dims(l, -1)
    s = tf.expand_dims(s, -1)

    x = tf.concat([tf.zeros_like(l), l, tf.zeros_like(l)], -1)
    y = tf.concat([h, l, s], -1)

    return tf.where(condition=tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(minc, maxc)), x=x, y=y)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    """
    HLS: Hue, Luminance, Saturation
    H: position in the spectrum
    L: color lightness
    S: color saturation
    """
    avatar = Image.open("hue.jpg")
    width, height = avatar.size
    print("width: {}, height: {}".format(width, height))
    img = np.array(avatar)
    img = img / 255.0
    print(img.shape)

    # # hue, luminance, saturation = rgb2hls(img)
    # hue, luminance, saturation = np_rgb2hls(img)

    img_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(img, tf.float32)
    hls = tf_rgb2hls(img_tensor)
    h, l, s = hls[:, :, 0], hls[:, :, 1], hls[:, :, 2]

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        hue, luminance, saturation = sess.run([h, l, s])
        scipy.misc.imsave("hls_h_.jpg", hue)
        scipy.misc.imsave("hls_l_.jpg", luminance)
        scipy.misc.imsave("hls_s_.jpg", saturation)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is looking for a self-contained solution (I *really* didn't want to add OpenCV as a dependency), I rewrote the official python `colorsys` `rgb_to_hls()` and `hls_to_rgb()` functions to be usable for numpy:

```py
import numpy as np

def rgb_to_hls(rgb_array: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Expects an array of shape (X, 3), each row being RGB colours.
    Returns an array of same size, each row being HLS colours.
    Like `colorsys` python module, all values are between 0 and 1.

    NOTE: like `colorsys`, this uses HLS rather than the more usual HSL
    """
    assert rgb_array.ndim == 2
    assert rgb_array.shape[1] == 3
    assert np.max(rgb_array) <= 1
    assert np.min(rgb_array) >= 0

    r, g, b = rgb_array.T.reshape((3, -1, 1))
    maxc = np.max(rgb_array, axis=1).reshape((-1, 1))
    minc = np.min(rgb_array, axis=1).reshape((-1, 1))

    sumc = (maxc+minc)
    rangec = (maxc-minc)

    with np.errstate(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore'):
        rgb_c = (maxc - rgb_array) / rangec
    rc, gc, bc = rgb_c.T.reshape((3, -1, 1))

    h = (np.where(minc == maxc, 0, np.where(r == maxc, bc - gc, np.where(g == maxc, 2.0+rc-bc, 4.0+gc-rc)))
         / 6) % 1
    l = sumc/2.0
    with np.errstate(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore'):
        s = np.where(minc == maxc, 0,
                     np.where(l < 0.5, rangec / sumc, rangec / (2.0-sumc)))

    return np.concatenate((h, l, s), axis=1)


def hls_to_rgb(hls_array: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Expects an array of shape (X, 3), each row being HLS colours.
    Returns an array of same size, each row being RGB colours.
    Like `colorsys` python module, all values are between 0 and 1.

    NOTE: like `colorsys`, this uses HLS rather than the more usual HSL
    """
    ONE_THIRD = 1 / 3
    TWO_THIRD = 2 / 3
    ONE_SIXTH = 1 / 6

    def _v(m1, m2, h):
        h = h % 1.0
        return np.where(h < ONE_SIXTH, m1 + (m2 - m1) * h * 6,
                        np.where(h < .5, m2,
                                 np.where(h < TWO_THIRD, m1 + (m2 - m1) * (TWO_THIRD - h) * 6,
                                          m1)))


    assert hls_array.ndim == 2
    assert hls_array.shape[1] == 3
    assert np.max(hls_array) <= 1
    assert np.min(hls_array) >= 0

    h, l, s = hls_array.T.reshape((3, -1, 1))
    m2 = np.where(l < 0.5, l * (1 + s), l + s - (l * s))
    m1 = 2 * l - m2

    r = np.where(s == 0, l, _v(m1, m2, h + ONE_THIRD))
    g = np.where(s == 0, l, _v(m1, m2, h))
    b = np.where(s == 0, l, _v(m1, m2, h - ONE_THIRD))

    return np.concatenate((r, g, b), axis=1)


def _test1():
    import colorsys
    rgb_array = np.array([[.5, .5, .8], [.3, .7, 1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [.5, .5, .5]])
    hls_array = rgb_to_hls(rgb_array)
    for rgb, hls in zip(rgb_array, hls_array):
        assert np.all(abs(np.array(colorsys.rgb_to_hls(*rgb) - hls) < 0.001))
    new_rgb_array = hls_to_rgb(hls_array)
    for hls, rgb in zip(hls_array, new_rgb_array):
        assert np.all(abs(np.array(colorsys.hls_to_rgb(*hls) - rgb) < 0.001))
    assert np.all(abs(rgb_array - new_rgb_array) < 0.001)
    print("tests part 1 done")

def _test2():
    import colorsys
    hls_array = np.array([[0.6456692913385826, 0.14960629921259844, 0.7480314960629921], [.3, .7, 1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [.5, .5, .5]])
    rgb_array = hls_to_rgb(hls_array)
    for hls, rgb in zip(hls_array, rgb_array):
        assert np.all(abs(np.array(colorsys.hls_to_rgb(*hls) - rgb) < 0.001))
    new_hls_array = rgb_to_hls(rgb_array)
    for rgb, hls in zip(rgb_array, new_hls_array):
        assert np.all(abs(np.array(colorsys.rgb_to_hls(*rgb) - hls) < 0.001))
    assert np.all(abs(hls_array - new_hls_array) < 0.001)
    print("All tests done")

def _test():
    _test1()
    _test2()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    _test()
```

(see [gist](https://gist.github.com/reinhrst/2d693a16c04861a8fbc5253938312410))

(off topic: converting the other functions in the same way is actually a great training for someone wanting to get their hands dirty with `numpy` (or other SIMD / GPU) programming). Let me know if you do so :)

---

edit: `rgb_to_hsv` and `hsv_to_rgb` now also in the gist.